# Typescript decorators & generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-decorator

I'm a bit new in Typescript. I try to define a decorator that will add some metadata to a class. But I get some compiler errors that I don't succeed to solve.

Here is my code :

```
import "reflect-metadata";

function DomainEvent<T extends object>(eventName: string) {
    return function <T extends object> (target: T): T {
        Reflect.defineMetadata('custom:annotation:DomainEvent', eventName, target as Object)

        return class extends target {
            constructor(...args: any[]) {
                super(...args);
            }
        } as T
    }
}

@DomainEvent('articles/created')
class ArticleCreated {
    id: string

    constructor(id: string) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

const event = new ArticleCreated('test'))
// returns the event name.
console.log(Reflect.getMetadata('custom:annotation:DomainEvent', ArticleCreated))
```

And the errors :

```
[0] src/custom/domain-event.ts(5,66): error TS2345: Argument of type 'T' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Object'.
[0] src/custom/domain-event.ts(7,30): error TS2507: Type 'T' is not a constructor function type.
```

Please help me to solve these errors.

Comment: Please note that these are now considered *experimental/legacy decorators* as opposed to [decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#decorators) as they will be implemented in JavaScript...  we might want to start referring to them as "legacy" from now on in Stack Overflow.